# Ubuntu 15.04 application audio status bar widget

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, 15.04, volume-control

I am looking for a widget that would reside in the status bar of my Ubuntu 15.04 install.  There is currently the standard volume control which controls the master volume.  What I am looking for is a widget that when you click on it gives you direct access to control the volume level of specific applications as a subset of the master volume.  The functionality is currently available with the standard volume widget but required several levels of navigation.  I am looking for something that would make it quicker for me to adjust volume.

I have researched several alternatives such as `pavucontrol` which is great but is not a widget.  I have also seen a KDE option but that also will not work.  I am running stock Ubuntu 15.04.  Any ideas?

I would love something like the image below but as a widget and not a stand alone window.  Though I just need basic volume control, not channel control or anything fancy like that.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Why not just go to KDE? It looks great on 14.04.

Comment: I have just never been a fan of kde.

Comment: Why? Is it the opacity?

Comment: Just the default installed apps I guess. I haven't tried it in a few years and I may just be stuck in my ways.  I am downloading Kubuntu 15.04 now and I will try it in a VM and see what I think. Thanks for the idea.  Maybe it will be my answer.  I'll follow up and let you know

Comment: OK. You can just install `kubuntu-desktop` on your actual machine and choose it at login, which might be easier to do.

Comment: I installed kubuntu-desktop and also tried the ISO in a virtual machine.  I just dont like it as much.  There are numerous reasons as to why.  I LOVE the application volume control that comes standard but that is about the only item I like as much or more than the standard Ubuntu interface.  There must be some way to do this in Ubuntu.  Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: I'm not sure what the package is called, but searching "kde volume control package name" should tell you. Look it up in the Software Center and run it from the terminal.

Comment: But I am running unity... Can I run a single KDE widget on a Unity status bar?

Comment: The programs can be run separately, for the most part. Just hope you get lucky.